# Moving images is very slow

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project that involves saving a lot of images to a database. However, I made a mistake. I included the actual image in the **image** table, which is the same table that holds the metadata. This requires me to always load the image even when I only need the metadata, which occurs quite often.

I won't go into much more detail about the metadata since it is not relevant for this question. But basically it is a timestamp, varchar(255) and two booleans (so nothing crazy).

In order to fix my mistake I created a new table called **ImageBlob** that contains just the image and an Id that is referenced by the the entities in the **Image** table.

I then wrote a piece of code (using EF Core 3.0.0)
to move the data from the **Image** table to the **ImageBlob** table. This code however, is incredibly slow. (It has been running for about 12 hours and it is only 40% done.)

I am trying to move 120.000 images. There is a total of 200.000 records from which 80.000 do not contain an image. The entire database is about 150GB.

My question is: Am I overlooking something or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Code to move the images:

```cs
using (var context = new MakeModelContext())
            {
                List<int> imageIds = context.Images
                   .Where(x => x.IsAcquired)
                   .Select(x => x.Id)
                   .ToList();

                foreach (int imageId in imageIds)
                {
                    Image image = context.Images.Where(x => x.Id == imageId).Single();

                    if (image.Picture != null)
                    {
                        image.ImageBlob = new ImageBlob(image.Picture);
                        image.Picture = null;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Image.cs:

```cs
public class Image
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public ImageBlob ImageBlob { get; set; }

        // Metadata redacted
    }
```

ImageBlob.cs:

```cs
public class ImageBlob
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Blob { get; set; }

        public ImageBlob(byte[] blob)
        {
            this.Blob = blob;
        }
    }
```

#### EDIT: Solution as suggested by sdi

Thanks for your reply. I modified the code to process the images in batches of 100. While I did expect some overhead from the individual queries I did not expect it to have such a big of an impact on the performance!

I did consider SaveChangesASync() but I think this might cause conflicts as the program might fetch images that are already being moved but for which the changes have not yet been fully saved.

That being said. The performance still is not great, but definitely adequate for a one time operation. I am currently managing about 6MB/s.

Modified code:

```cs
using (var context = new MakeModelContext())
            {
                bool done = false;

                while (!done)
                {
                    List<Image> image_batch = context.Images
                        .Where(x => x.IsAcquired && x.Picture != null)
                        .Take(100)
                        .ToList();

                    if (image_batch.Count < 100)
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }

                    foreach (Image image in image_batch)
                    {
                        image.ImageBlob = new ImageBlob(image.Picture);
                        image.Picture = null;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can also keep the table with all data, and split it into two entities in your model. See this article: [Table Splitting In Entity Framework Core 2.0
](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-2-0/). Or use simple SQL to copy data:  insert into ImageBlob(Id, Blob) select Id, Blob from Image

Comment: I did think of doing it with raw SQL, but wasn't sure how to add the foreign key reference to the images table.

Also splitting the data across tables, seems like an interesting concept which I will definitely consider using in the future.

Comment: @JoelRiverFiend EF Core doesn't replace SQL, it's used to make it easier to map objects to tables. In this case you have no objects, so ORMs are the wrong solution. Worse, you're pulling the data all the way to the client even though you don't need it at all. You only modify the *server's* data. As for FKs, EF doesn't guess them, it uses the ones you provided through configuration

Comment: What is your code trying to do anyway? Extract the data in `Picture` to another table? And then delete all `Picture` data or perhaps, remove the column entirely? `INSERT INTO ImageBlobs(ImageId,PictureField) SELECT ID,Picture from Images` will copy all the data from `Images` to `ImageBlobs` and set the `ImageId` field to the parent `Image`.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The goal was to move the image from the `Image` table to the `ImageBlob` table. Currently my database model is configured so that an `Image`   has one `ImageBlob` so I need the id of an `ImageBlob` to be stored in the `Image` table.

Comment: @JoelRiverFiend why? Is one Blob used by multiple images? Even so, it's easy to do this. You can use the `OUTPUT` clause in `INSERT` to extract the new IDs and store it in a table variable. Post the table creation scripts so people can create a specific solution

Comment: @JoelRiverFiend if you search for table refactoring scripts, you'll see that vertical partitioning (splitting a table's columns) is nothing new. There are ways to optimize it too

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos. I did not know this. Thanks for pointing this out! The currently solution has almost finished moving the data, so I wont be trying this at the moment, but in the future I definitely will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to extract the data in the `Picture` column into a separate table.

**Image -> Blob**

Assuming you have these tables :

```
CREATE TABLE Images (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    ...,
    Picture varbinary(max)
)

CREATE TABLE Blobs (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    ImageID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY FK_Blob_Image REFERENCES Images(ID),
    Picture varbinary(max),
    ...
)
```

You can copy the `Picture` data to the table with just :

```
INSERT INTO Blobs(ImageId,Picture) 
SELECT ID,Picture 
from Images
```

After that, you can clear the existing data with :

```
UPDATE Images
Set Picture=null
```

Using an ORM is completely inappropriate in this case. No Objects are involved and there's no reason to pull the server data to the client only to send it back

**Blob->Image**

When the order is reversed, the OUTPUT clause in the INPUT statement can be used to extract the new BlobIDs and set them to the Image table.

```
CREATE TABLE Images (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    ...,
    BlobID FOREIGN KEY FK_Image_Blob REFERENCES Blobs(ID),
    Picture varbinary(max)
)

CREATE TABLE Blobs (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    Picture varbinary(max),
    ...
)
```

With

```
declare @blobImages table(BlobID int,ImageID int)

INSERT INTO Blobs(ImageId,Picture) 
    OUTPUT inserted.ID ,inserted.ImageID
    INTO @blobImages
SELECT ID,Picture 
from Images

UPDATE Images
SET 
    Picture=null,
    BlobID=b.BlobID
FROM Images 
INNER JOIN @blobImages b on b.ImageID=Images.ID
```

FR

Comment: Thanks. I agree this would've been a better solution. Would have used it if I had known about it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> I then wrote a piece of code (using EF Core 3.0.0) to move the data from the Image table to the ImageBlob table.

So to move things around in the database, you chose to get every single image to your client computer and then send it back to the server. That's not very efficient.

You could just use a single SQL command to the server to do that all on the server and never send a single image back and forth.

Now I don't know what your table look like, but doing SQL on the server for a purely server-side operation will probably take seconds or if it's a lot of data maybe minutes.

Comment: The database is hosted on the same remote device as where the code is hosted, so I didn't really see this as an issue. For a server side approach I would've needed to somehow retrieve the id of every newly created ImageBlob entity and insert it into corresponding Image entity and I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: @JoelRiverFiend it's a *huge* issue. You're still pulling a ton of data from one process optimized for mass data handling into another that can only deal with individual items, and then send it back. The inter-process communication is *several* orders of magnitude slower than the buffered in-process operations performed by SQL Server

Comment: @JoelRiverFiend you end up buffering *all* data at least twice - in the server's buffers *and* the client. The client will keep *all* the data in memory until the GC runs

Answer (score 0):

for each id of imageIds you open a connection to the database and load a image, you could try to batch it (so that you load like 50 at once), this should already increase the speed? same goes with saveasync(), not after each new image but after the batch was created/inserted

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please refer to the initial question for my implementation.

Comment: Pulling all data to the client only to send it back to the server is not a good solution